# Android: Dynamic dependency addition in gradle using plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Is it possible to add dependency in android project dynamically depending on configuration of device used, can I add this script in gradle plugin?

Comment: Did you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
if(myconfig=="device one"){
    dependencies.compile 'com.example.android:example:1.0.10'
} else {
    dependencies.compile 'com.example.android:example:1.0.9'
}
```